# Magento: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Can't connect to mysql: Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'

Tags: php, mysql, magento

Hello I am getting this strange issue with magento while trying to install a new theme. Its says using password No but I have supplied the correct password. I would greatly appreciate your help in resolving this issue.

> Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Can't connect to mysql: Access denied for user 'mdayurve_letr885'@'localhost' (using password: NO)' in /home/mdayurve/public_html/letterfloret/install.lib.php:30

Stack trace:

```
#0 /home/mdayurve/public_html/letterfloret/install-em0022.php(34): open_db(string, string, string, string, string)
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home/mdayurve/public_html/letterfloret/install.lib.php on line 30
```

Comment: A file `letterfloret/install.lib.php` is not part of standard Magento, so most probably nearly nobody except you knows, what this file looks like or does. Please post the code of that file.

Comment: please find the code at: https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=379B67DCC866C48F!106

Answer (score 0):

Check your local.xml and see the configs of database

Comment: This is the local.xml. Its all the same
                    [code]<host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
                    <username><![CDATA[mdayurve_letr885]]></username>
                    <password><![CDATA[5w7rSbme1P]]></password>
                    <dbname><![CDATA[mdayurve_letr885]]></dbname>
                    <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
                    <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
                    <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
                    <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
                    <active>1</active>[code]

Comment: this seems right config. but seemingly this install dont tanking this config to access your database becouse this config have password and exception says Password: NO. So, my sugest is: take this string "mdayurve_letr885", and if you using eclipse press Ctrl+h and file search, and search this string around your project. Takes where found and look the configs as right.

Comment: I tried the same. I searched the whole files on my webhost using extexplorer but could not find another instance of the same. @Guerra

Answer (score 0):

Please check it your old theme working fine so you have no error in local.xml, but if not so make sure correct the information of Database in local.xml

Refer to this link for more information about that.

> http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/using-local-xml-for-overriding-or-updating-xml-structure/
>   http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/5-useful-tricks-for-your-magento-local-xml/

Comment: thanks for the reply but I am trying to install a new theme I bought. they gave me this php file that I should run in order to fully & correctly configure the theme. But the file is not reading the mysql database I guess. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Yes, the default theme is working just fine: letterfloret.com. I am a novice when it comes to databases. how can I cross check if local.xml have the correct configuration information?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the people who created your theme have also created a **separate** database method.  The error message Magento throws off when it can't connect to a database looks like this

```
Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)";i:1;s:3152:"#0 /Users/alanstorm/Sites2012/magento1point7pointzeropoint1.dev/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(96): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()
```

The wording of your error message

```
Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Can't connect to mysql: Access denied for user 'mdayurve_letr885'@'localhost' (using password: NO)' in /home/mdayurve/public_html/letterfloret/install.lib.php:30

Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Can't connect to mysql: Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
```

I'd look in the theme files for PHP function calls that establish a second database connection.

Posting the contents of `install.lib.php` and `install-em0022.php` would help people debug your problem for you.

Update: If you take a look at `install-em0022.php`, the top of the file contains the following

```
/**
 * USER INSTRUCTION:
 *
 * 1. upload em0022-theme-package.zip, install-em0022.php and install.lib.php to your magento folder (/public_html)
 * 2. configure install-em0022.php at CONFIGURE HERE section
 * 3. run install-em0022.php from your web browser: http://www.yourdomain.com/install-em0022.php
 * 4. delete em0022-theme-package.zip, install-em0022.php and install.lib.php
 */


################################################################################
### CONFIGURE HERE
################################################################################

$dbhost = "localhost";  # Database host name
$dbname = ""; # Database name
$dbuser = "root"; # Database username
$dbpass = ""; # Database password
$dbport = ""; # Database port
$adminuser = 'admin'; // magento admin username
$adminpass = ''; // magento admin password
```

Apparently you need to duplicate your database credentials here to "install" this theme.

Comment: Here is the Skydrive link to the file install.lib.php: https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=379B67DCC866C48F!106

Comment: The Skydrive link to the file install-em0022.php would be: https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=379B67DCC866C48F!105

Comment: yes I did that and I was left with the error message I reported.

Comment: If you would like, I will give you the login details of my cpanel

Comment: I got a reply from EMthemes who provided me this theme. They confirmed that "Hi,

Please check the config file that connect to MySql -> app/etc/local.xml
<host><![CDATA[.............]]></host>
<username><![CDATA[...........]]></username>
<password><![CDATA[...............]]></password>
<dbname><![CDATA[............]]></dbname>
"